# Excel VBA: using autofilter smartly

Tags: string, excel, vba, autofilter

So, here's my question...

I have a column with strings looking like this:

"2,3" 
"1,2" 
"2" 
"3,22,1" 
"32,5"

Now, what I would like to do is to find a way (without writing my own function for it) to filter everything that doesn't contain "2" (the rows with "32" or "22" need to be filtered out).

So, for example, by keeping only "2", from the list above, I would like to get:
"2,3"
"1,2"
"2"

I am now filtering using:
1. contains "2," OR contains ",2" OR equals "2"

Unfortunately, "3,22,1" will be kept by the first two filters and "32,5" is kept by the second one.

Any ideas on how to do this with the filter function?
Like I said, I can write a function for it, but I'd keep my code minimal and learn how to use VBA better, instead.

Thank you in advance!
Riccardo

Comment: I just thought of a solution.. need to test,  no time now..
 ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("2,*", "*,2","2",",2,")

Comment: cool, if that doesn't work i'm pretty sure theres a way to loop through the cells and use InStr to check based on a criteria! I can help with that if needed but good luck in the meantime :)

Comment: Using  autofilter separately for each "*,2"  "2,*",   "2",  "*,2,*" works fine.
When I try to combine them using an array like this:

Selection.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("*,2", "2,*", "2", "*,2,*")

It is only giving me the filter on the last element of the array.

I need to find a way to apply 4 conditions linked by OR. I know that in principle one can only use 2, but there MUST be a workaround. I thought using the Array() was one, but it isn't working for me.

ANY IDEAS?

Comment: @Riccardo I don't think you can do this with the `AutoFilter`.  You could do it with the `AdvancedFilter` easily by writing an Excel formula or UDF that tests for `2`.  Of course, it might be quicker to just roll your own.

Comment: @Riccardo Actually, you could do it with AutoFilter and a helper column which contains a formula that returns true or false.  Then filter on the helper column. The array-entered formula `=OR(EXACT("2",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A6,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))-1)*99+1,99))))` can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still kind of unsure what you want to remove and what to keep, but using your array of criteria, how about this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("2,", ",2","2",",2,"),_ 
Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Worth noting it's a more foolproof way when writing macros to refer to the sheet directly otherwise they can occasionally get lost in the script :)

Comment: If you don't use the * you are not filtering by "contains", but by match and then you're getting only the row containing exactly "2". When I use the * in the array, however, it doesn't work (while it works for the single filtering "2,*", etc.)